# Many to many relation for self join table with yourself

Tags: frameworks, entity

I have two tables with names User and Role that have many to many relationship with each other. I have made this relationship with entity in MVC.

Now I want UserRole navigation table that has many to many relation with itself.
Thus UserRole has many to many relation with UserRole.

How can I implement this model?

Comment: Please provide a mock up of what you are trying to achieve so we can pin-point the problem.

Comment: What is your programming language? Wich SQL server are you using (MsSQL, PostgreSQL, other)? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47115791/edit) your question and add details. Also read about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: C# and MsSQL in visual studio and entity framework code first